# Multi-Attribute Sorting and Filtering on an Array of Structs

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, struct

I have an array of structs.  Each struct has the following two attributes:

- win %
- # of wins

I want to sort the array of structs by win %; however, for only those structs with at least 3 wins.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen to the structs with fewer wins. Perhaps some example data would help?

Comment: @Chris: The title says "Filtering", so I just assumed he wants to filter them out.

Comment: Fair point. If so, sepp2k's answer is indeed good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `select` to take only the objects with at least 3 wins, then use sort_by to sort by the percentage:

```
array.select {|x| x.num_of_wins >= 3}.sort_by {|x| x.win_percent}
```